# Adding remote repository jar file as dependency in pom.xml maven

Tags: java, maven

Is it possible to add remote repository jar file (https://repo.ah/lib/abc.jar) in maven pom.xml as dependency in java project. if so, can you please share example.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to add a complete repository as a dependency. This doesn't make sense, because a repository can contain ten thousands of artifacts.

If your project requires artifacts which are not hosted in the standard remote repository, you can specify this via the `<repositories>` tag in your `pom.xml` .

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

More Informations:
[Introduction to Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)
[Setting up Multiple Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html)

Comment: I do not need complete repository as a dependency. Just need one artifact (a jar file - https://repo.ah/lib/abc.jar). and this file is not generated with maven, so doesn't have <dependency> tag details.

Comment: ok, now I understand, thanks to this comment. Look at this [guide: installing third party jar files](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

Comment: as per the guide, we have to place .jar file in the local repository. but my requirement is to pull from artifactory url. I can't place this jar in local as it changes frequently. If i can get from url, will always have latest in my project.

Comment: Why didn' t you tell this in your question ???  It's painful to help someone who gives relevant  informations by bits and pieces ....

Comment: I believe i clearly specified my question. Is it possible to add remote repository jar file (https://repo.ah/lib/abc.jar) in maven pom.xml as dependency. Please let me know if it doesn't make sense still.

Comment: you have to upload abc.jar to your artifactory repository. The Maven coordinates which have to specify are your choice. After that, you can add a `<dependency>` entry to your `pom.xml`. This requires that you have configured your artifactory repository well

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you mentioned that the URL is an Artifactory.

So just add the Artifactory as `<repository>` to your `settings.xml` and then you can use the jar in your application.