# How to add external jar at a specific URL (NOT LOCAL) to a maven project?

Tags: java, maven

I can find a lot of questions on how to import an external jar, already on the machine, in a maven project.

But how can I do that for a jar downloadable via an URL ?

I've checked the [following](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html), but it is only for local jars.

Moreover, the [following](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies) has no information about urL or any non local source.

Is there any example, or can you provide one, showing how to do such a thing if it is possible ?

For example, with my jar at `http://myjar.com/myjardownload`

Does something like this exist ?

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysuperjar</groupId>
            <artifactId>jar-super-nice</artifactId>
            <url>http://myjar.com/myjardownload</url>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Possible (non helpful) dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703394/adding-remote-repository-jar-file-as-dependency-in-pom-xml-maven

Answer (score 0):

No.

You need to download the jar and upload it to your company Nexus/Artifactory.

Alternatively, install it into your local repository.

The best alternative is to find out whether this jar can be drawn from any Maven repository on the internet and then add that Maven repository either to your `settings.xml` or to your company Nexus/Artifactory.